# Why CGI.pm upload old revision of a file on successful new file upload?

Tags: perl, upload, cgi

I am using [CGI.pm](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CGI.pm/) version 3.10 for file upload using Perl. I have a Perl script which uploads the file and one of my application keeps track of different revisions of the uploaded document with check-in check-out facility.

Re-creational steps:

- I have done a checkout(download a file) using my application (which is web based uses apache).
- Logout from current user session.
- Login again with same credentials and then check-in (upload) a new file.

Output:

- Upload successful
- Perl upload script shows the correct uploaded data
- New revision of the file created

Output is correct and expected except the one case which is the issue

Issue:

- The content of the newly uploaded file are same as the content of the last uploaded revision in DB.

I am using a temp folder for copying the new content and if I print the new content in upload script then it comes correct. I have no limit on CGI upload size. It seems somewhere in CGI environment it fails might be the version i am using. I am not using taint mode.

Can anybody helps me to understand what might be the possible reason?

Comment: You should try to trace content of the file in some log. You'll see on which step it's changing the way it should not. It's very hard to understand what happening using information you've provided. It's too high level. Please try to *localize* the error and attach code causing it.

Comment: You have to show some code. Build a minimal test case that exhibits the problem so that other people can reproduce it on their own.

Comment: It's very hard to understand your problem. You get the latest rev of a file from the DB, download it, modify it locally and reupload it. There it is uploaded fine to a temp folder. When you try to load (or compare ?) it with the DB, you realize that the temp file now has the content of the file in the DB. Is this right ? If so, my guess would be that your code to check the DB took the file in that DB and replaced the temporary one with it. But with your high-level description, it's hard to tell why. As Ivan suggested, you should check your file at various steps of the process to debug it.

Comment: Start the normal debugging process. Examine the data at each step to see what's happening.

Comment: Thanks for all suggestions. I will debug and share the findings.. just want to check if CGI.pm 3.10 is too old to use in 2010, shall I move to newer version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. The reason was destination path of the copied file was not correct, this was because my application one of event maps the path of copied file to different directory and this path is storing in user session. This happens only when I run the event just before staring upload script. This was the reason that it was hard to catch. As upload script is designed to pick the new copied file from same path so it always end up uploading the same file in DB with another revision. The new copied file lying in new path.

Solved by mapping correct path before upload.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're getting the old file name stuck in the file upload field. Not sure if that can happen for filefield but this is a feature for other field types.

Try adding the -nosticky pragma, eg, `use CGI qw(-nosticky :all);`. Another pragma to try is -private_tempfiles, which should prevent the user from "eavesdropping" even on their own uploads.

Of course, it could be that you need to localize (*my*) some variable or add -force to the filefield.